# Modisco generates uml with only public attributes

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, reverse-engineering

I am using Modisco to create UML diagrams from my Java Code in Eclipse.

I follow these steps:

1)Selecting the project: Right Click->Discovery -> Discoverers -> Discover KDM Code from Java Project

2)Selecting the KDM file: Right Click->Discovery -> Discoverers -> Generate UML File

Then I use Papyrus to view the model Modisco's generated.

The problem is that every single attribute is public: the private ones are showing as public, too, I checked the xml.

How can I make Modisco show attributes with the right scope?